# Numpy array with values that update

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to create a automatically updating Numpy array?

For example:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
b = numpy.array([a[0]+1,a[1]+2,a[2]+3,a[3]+4])
a[0] = 5
```

Output:

```
>>>print(b)
>>>[6, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: That's not the optimal way to think about modifying arrays.  Focus on whole array operations, not element by element ones.

Comment: Isn't this just `b = a + np.arange(len(a)) + 1`?

Comment: This is just `a * 2`, or `a + a`. The way to "store" operations is to use functions. Lazy evaluation is not directly supported by numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Not if the array elements are stored by value. However numpy supports arrays of objects, so you could store lamdas or something and achieve something similar...although it's probably not what you want.

Ex:

```py
a = np.array([1])
b = np.array([ lambda: a[0] + 1 ])
a[0] = 5

print (b[0]())
# 6
```

Comment: Might as well use a list for this.